# GTK+ 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER' failed

Tags: c++, gtk

I am learning GTK+ and as an exercise I am trying to make a simple GUI text editor. Here is simplified and shorter version of my code that illustrates the problem I am having:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

class App
{
protected:
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    GtkWidget *view;
};

class Window: public App
{
public:
    Window()
    {
        window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
        g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), 0);
    }
    void show()
    {
        gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    }
};

class Editor: public App
{
public:
    Editor()
    {
        view = gtk_text_view_new();
        buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view));
        gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, "TEXT", -1);
        add();
    }
private:
    void add()
    {
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), view);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    Window *w = new Window();
    Editor *e = new Editor();
    w->show();
    delete w;
    delete e;
    gtk_main();
}
```

The program compiles and runs but it should show on the screen editable widget with text "TEXT" written into it, which it doesn't.
Running this program in terminal shows this message: `(test.o:23861): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_add: assertion 'GTK_IS_CONTAINER (container)' failed`.
My question is what causes this and how I can fix it.

Comment: Without knowing anything about *gtk*, I would say that where you do `GTK_CONTAINER(window)`, `window` is probably not a container

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: @Justin no, windows are containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copies of the instance variables in both `class Window` and `class Editor` that are inherited from `class App` are **unique**. You can't share data like that; `Window::window` and `Editor::window` are different variables, and `Editor::window` never gets initialized.

This is a fundamental part of how inheritance works in C++. If you are not familiar with that, you should read a C++ book or tutorial on the subject.

If you are familiar with that and just forgot, then what you should be doing if you are going down this route is just have `class App` have all your program logic in it, and have `main()` work exclusively with an instance of `class App`. You should also consider gtkmm, which is a C++ wrapper on top of GTK+ that allows you to work with GTK+ as if it was C++.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that `window` variable is the same one in `Window` and `Editor` classes.